# Struggling with Duplicate Java JRE version on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk, openjdk

I have installed java jdk 9 and java jre 9 on ubuntu and set the path of both to `/etc/environment` as `/usr/local/jdk-9.0.4:/usr/local/jre-9.0.4/bin` then I tested `javac -version` which prints jdk9 but when I run `java -version` it prints

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.17.10.2-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

I don't know where the openjdk is installed. I think it is installed with the MAVEN.

Here is the `/etc/environment` content

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/jdk-9.0.4/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/jdk-9.0.4:/usr/local/jre-9.0.4/bin"
```

Comment: How did you install jdk/jre9? Via apt? What is the output of `update-java-alternatives --list` (may need sudo, but not sure)?

Comment: openJDK install automatically when I installed maven. but the other version java 9 is installed in /usr/local by self. extracting the zip file there.

Answer (score 1):

When you installed maven, openjdk-8-jre-headless was installed as a dependency. The Java Runtime Environment (jre) does include the `java` binary, but not the Java compiler (`javac`). The `java` binary (or, to be more specific, a link to it) now resides in `/usr/bin`. Since the `PATH`-variable is processed left-to-right, executing `java` executes `/usr/bin/java`, whereas `javac` executes `/usr/local/jdk-9.0.4/bin/javac` because it was not found in any other folder contained in `PATH`. You can check this yourself using the `which` command, e.g. `which java` or `which javac`.

The openjdk8 jre is most likely installed in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8...` and its binaries are linked in `/usr/bin` by the [Debian Alternatives System](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives).